# Mac Mini with Linux

Tags: macos, mac-mini, unix

I have a Mac Mini (6,1) without an optical drive and I would like to put Debian testing on it instead of OS X. I cannot find a complete and concise guide to doing this on the mac's without the optical drives.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Use a USB stick to boot off.

Answer (score 2):

You can download a live or an install disk image and copy it on an USB drive. Just look at [these instructions](http://www.debian.org/CD/faq/#write-usb) from the Debian installation guide.

For more detailed instructions, read the [Ubuntu guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx) for creating a live stick. The procedure is identical; just do that with the Debian image.